Using .assign in a dataframe with a custom function
Good Morning
I have a question which I'd be very grateful for your help / advice. I am trying to create a column in a dataframe and passing a custom function that will assign the suffix to the day i.e. 1st, 2nd etc. I have managed to do this with .apply, however I would like to do this with .assign and I am getting the error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). My question is how can I do this (method 2) and is there a better way of doing all of this? Many thanks in advance for your time and help. The code is as follows:
import pandas as pd



def datesuffix(dy):
    
    if 4 <= dy <= 20 or 24 <= dy <= 30:
        suffix = "th"
    else:
        suffix = ["st", "nd", "rd"][dy % 10 - 1]
    retval = str(dy)+ str(suffix)
    return(retval)


def updatedf(_df):
    _df['DayAmend'] = _df.apply(lambda x: datesuffix(x.dateday),axis=1)
    return(_df)

df = pd.DataFrame(
                     {
                         'datehour':['1','2','3','4','1','2','3','4'],
                         'dateday':['1','1','1','1','2','2','2','2']

                     }
                )

print(df)
df = df.astype({'datehour':'int32','dateday':'int32'})
    

# Method 1 (Return whole df)
newdf = updatedf(df)
print(newdf)

# Method 2 (Use assign with lambda)
newdf1 = (df
         .assign(DayAmend = lambda x:datesuffix(x.dateday))
         )
print(newdf1)
print('complete')

Thanks
Steven

You need to apply your function to each item, you can use a list comprehension:
newdf1 = df.assign(DayAmend = lambda x: [datesuffix(y) for y in x.dateday])

Or:
newdf1 = df.assign(DayAmend = lambda x: list(map(datesuffix, x.dateday)))

Output:
   datehour  dateday DayAmend
0         1        1      1st
1         2        1      1st
2         3        1      1st
3         4        1      1st
4         1        2      2nd
5         2        2      2nd
6         3        2      2nd
7         4        2      2nd

Note that you could also use a pure pandas approach, get the last digit with mod, then map st/nd/rd and fix the special case of the tenths with a mask:
newdf1 = df.assign(DayAmend = lambda x: x['dateday']
                             .mod(10).map({1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'})
                             .fillna('th')
                             .mask(x['dateday'].between(10, 20), 'th')
                             .radd(x['dateday'].astype(str))
                  )

As a named function:
def datesuffix(s):
    return (s.mod(10).map({1: 'st', 2: 'nd', 3: 'rd'})
             .mask(s.between(10, 20)).fillna('th')
             .radd(s.astype(str))
           )

newdf1 = df.assign(DayAmend=lambda x: datesuffix(x['dateday']))

Example:
    dateday DayAmend
0         1      1st
1         2      2nd
2         3      3rd
3         4      4th
4         5      5th
5         6      6th
6         7      7th
7         8      8th
8         9      9th
9        10     10th
10       11     11th
11       12     12th
12       13     13th
13       14     14th
14       15     15th
15       16     16th
16       17     17th
17       18     18th
18       19     19th
19       20     20th
20       21     21st
21       22     22nd
22       23     23rd
23       24     24th
24       25     25th
25       26     26th
26       27     27th
27       28     28th
28       29     29th
29       30     30th
30       31     31st


Just for completeness, be aware that there are libraries that do this (for example inflect)

Use Series.apply with your custom function:
newdf1 = df.assign(DayAmend = lambda x: x.dateday.apply(datesuffix))

Another idea is mapping values by dictionary for improve performance:
d = {1: '1st', 2: '2nd', 3: '3rd', 4: '4th', 5: '5th', 
     6: '6th', 7: '7th', 8: '8th', 9: '9th', 10: '10th',
     11: '11th', 12: '12th', 13: '13th', 14: '14th', 
     15: '15th', 16: '16th', 17: '17th', 18: '18th', 
     19: '19th', 20: '20th', 21: '21st', 22: '22nd', 
     23: '23rd', 24: '24th', 25: '25th', 26: '26th', 
     27: '27th', 28: '28th', 29: '29th', 30: '30th', 31: '31st'}

newdf1 = df.assign(DayAmend = lambda x: x.dateday.map(d))

print(newdf1)
   datehour  dateday DayAmend
0         1        1      1st
1         2        1      1st
2         3        1      1st
3         4        1      1st
4         1        2      2nd
5         2        2      2nd
6         3        2      2nd
7         4        2      2nd

Performance:
#310000 values
df = pd.DataFrame({'dateday':list(range(1,32)) * 10000})
print(df)


In [38]: %timeit df.assign(DayAmend = lambda x: x.dateday.map(d))
8.16 ms ± 231 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [39]: %timeit df.assign(DayAmend = lambda x: x.dateday.apply(datesuffix))
207 ms ± 2.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

